# How can I capture traffic originating from my own Firefox Web Extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a Firefox Extension (*WebExtension*) which, as one of it's functions, needs to request resources from the network and override response headers, especially those that control how the browser treats the response (for example, gzip encoding should be removed from content-encoding to retrieve the 'raw' response).

The problem is that I cannot find a way to intercept requests, made by my extension. This works fine in Chrome, and I can intercept requests, made by the user directly.

This problem affects all webRequest handlers, but the example is for `onHeadersReceived` (simplified to the bare minimum):

```
function OnHeadersReceived(details){
    console.log('Received headers for ' + details.url);
}

chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(OnHeadersReceived, { urls: ['<all_urls>'] });
```

And here is a very simple example of the request:

```
fetch('http://www.alexa.com')
```

Same problem applies to `XMLHttpRequest`.

Any insight into this problem is appreciated. I know that Chrome does not allow to intercept requests, originated in other extensions, but has nothing against requests originated within your own extension.

**UPDATE**

Found a bug on BugZilla: [WebExtensions: webRequest listeners do not fire for XMLHttpRequest requests generated by the extension](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1273138)

Comment: If you're initiating this request yourself, you can pass all sorts of options to `fetch()` to customize headers, etc.:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalFetch/fetch#Parameters

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can. And I do, for some other cases. But in my case I need to get to some of the headers that will not be passed back to me. For example, if the browser understands the encoding, it will decode the response and strip down the header, and I don't want it to do so, though I do want the server to use that encoding. Example: download GZIPped page and forward it somewhere else. There are other use-cases as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if anybody else is wondering, this was an issue in Firefox and it was fixed in version 52.
Now all requests originating from the web extensions are also intercepted by handlers inside those extensions.